# What do the values for initialization method mean in statsmodels simple exponential smoothing?

Tags: time-series, python, smoothing, statsmodels, exponential-smoothing

I'm trying to use Statsmodels' [simple exponential smoothing](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.SimpleExpSmoothing.html#statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.SimpleExpSmoothing) for time series analysis.

There are various methods available for initializing the recursions (estimated, heuristic, known).
Can someone please explain what each of these options means?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

- The "known" method is if you know specific initial values that you want to use. If you select that method, you need to provide the values.
- The "heuristic" method is not based on a particular statistical principle, but instead chooses initial values based on a "reasonable approach" that was found to often work well in practice (it is described in section 2.6.1 of Hyndman et al. (2008) "Forecasting with Exponential Smoothing").
- The "estimated" method treats the initial values like parameters, and chooses them to minimize the sum of squared errors.